# Divide values in excel range by certain number using C#

Tags: c#, vba

I have this Excel range and I need to divide each cell content by 1000.
Looping through each cell over the range takes a lot of time.

Is there more efficient way to do this?

```
Dim c As Range 
For Each c In Range("B" & lastCol + 1 & ":Y" & lastRow) 
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then 
        c = c / 1000 
    End If 
Next
```

Need to convert above code into C#.
Thanks!

Comment: Please show your current code & explain the relevance of C# to your question

Comment: Why *divide* at all? If you want do display thousands instead of a raw number change the cells' formatting, eg to `#,##0,` as shown [here](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/format-numbers-in-thousands-and-millions-in-excel-reports/)

Comment: For speeding things up, it is advisable to hide the Excel application while the computation runs (`Application.Visible = False`). For translating to C#, this is unclear because while VBA is embedded into Excel, for a C# solution you have to agree on an API first: EPPlus, Interop, OleDb, ... / classic xls or OpenDocument/xlsx?

Comment: Hi  Panagiotis Kanavos, this is removing the figures after decimal.